# Regex forward and rear looking but exclude some criteria from match

Tags: regex, vb.net, string

I am using Regex to essentially extract an address. What I would like to do is to be able to use some regex like in my code block to extract the address, but in some cases to include the the starting point / criteria text in the returned match (e.g. STREET A, CNR) and in other cases take all text between two points, but not include one of the points in the returned match.

I am hoping someone might be able to help me with constructing a regex string what will return everything between two defined points in the string. The catch is sometimes the match should include the phrase from the regex (e.g. CNR) and other times different phrases should not be included in the match (e.g. Example Text).

This is an example Regex, in this case if STREET A existed it would include that in the match: 
    Regex = New Regex("( CNR| STREET A| EXAMPLE TEXT)(.*?)(?=\SVSE| M | SVC | SVSW | SVNE   |SVNW )", RegexOptions.RightToLeft)

**How can I use STREET A (or another phrase) as a marker in the above regex to return a regex match, but not actually include it in the match itself?**

Thanks!

I have included some extra information below which should hopefully help. These are some examples:

I have made Italic anything that is a criteria for match, then the items that I made Bold are what should match, these are just a few examples but in reality the regex can match on so many different things since the addresses are not always 123 example st.

@@ALERT SMPL1 F0000000 *GAS PIPE LEAK* **MAIN HWY SUBURB** *SVNW* 1111 A1 (375302) SMPLT1 [SMPL]

@@ALERT F0000000 SMPL1 STRUC1 SMOKE ALARM OPERATING AND SMELL OF SMOKE ***CNR*** SAMPLE ST/EXAMPLE ST SUBURB SVNE 1111 D7

@@ALERT SMPL1 F0000000 *CAR ACCIDENT - POSS PERSON TRAPPED* **MAIN HWY SUBURB** *SVNW* 1111 A1 (375302) SMPLT1 [SMPL]

@@ALERT F0000000 SMPL1 STRUC1 *GAS BOTTLE EXPLOSION* **SAMPLE ST/EXAMPLE ST SUBURB** *SVNE* 1111 D7

---- More Information ----

**This is what the regex currently is (and works), however I am having trouble managing to get multiple matches at the start to be excluded:**

```
(CNR|(([\d]+/[\d]+)|([\d]+ / [\d]+)|([\d]+-[\d]+)|([\d]+ - [\d]+)|( [\d]+ ))).*?(?=SV[NCSEW]| M )|(?<=GAS PIPE LEAK).*?(?=SV[NCSEW]| M )
```

**This is what i want to try and achieve: (but can't get working)**

```
(CNR|(([\d]+/[\d]+)|([\d]+ / [\d]+)|([\d]+-[\d]+)|([\d]+ - [\d]+)|( [\d]+ ))).*?(?=SV[NCSEW]| M )|(?<=(GAS PIPE LEAK|FIRE ALARM|SMOKE ALARMS|FIRE|)).*?(?=SV[NCSEW]| M )
```

**Here are some example strings:**

*@@ALERT F000000 BELM4 STRUC1 ACTIVATED SMOKE ALARMS JACARANDA ST SUBURB /ROAD ST M 000 K3 (000000)*

*@@ALERT F000000 BELM4 STRUC1 FIRE JACARANDA ST SUBURB /ROAD ST M 000 K3 (000000)*

*@@ALERT F000000 BELM4 STRUC1 EXPLOSION 123 JACARANDA ST SUBURB /ROAD ST M 000 K3 (000000)*

*@@ALERT F000000 BELM4 UNDEFINED FIRE JACARANDA ST SUBURB /ROAD ST M 000 K3 (000000)*

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand. Could you add some more example addresses and the required outputs for each, in your question?

Comment: Thanks @Jerry, I have put some examples up, basically where there is italic it is a the point at which the match starts / finishes, and where it is bold that is what I want the match to return, the problem is in some cases I want to return a string that includes where the match starts (e.g. where CNR is in the string), in other cases I want to return the string without where the criteria starts (e.g. if GAS PIPE LEAK is in the string and the string extracted is Main Hwy Suburb don't return GAS PIPE LEAK). How can I have a regex that allows me to do both e.g. Can I bracket and exclude a phrase

Comment: @user1829564 you have an extra `|` after FIRE, you should dump that

Answer (score 0):

You can use prefix and suffix match expressions and then or the results with your other matches

```
(?<=GAS PIPE LEAK).*?(?=SVN[EW])|(CNR|STREET A).*?(?=SVN[EW])
```

Comment: This is perfect, thanks for your help. With this is there any way I can have multiple excluded phrases, I tried ?<=(GAS PIPE LEAK|FIRE|RHS|ROOF|CAR ACCIDENT) but it would not work like that through the online testers.

Comment: @user1829564 Try `(?<=(GAS PIPE LEAK|FIRE|RHS|ROOF|CAR ACCIDENT))`

Comment: @user1829564 I gave that a go and it would not match anything. I have put some examples up and the regex I have working in the More Information section of my post, but can't manage to have multiple triggers at the start (e.g. GAS PIPE LEAK|FIRE|ROOF)

Comment: @user1829564 you put the regex in wrong in your example, you left an extra `|` at the end of the prefix match.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like that maybe:

```
((?<=(?:GAS PIPE LEAK|CAR ACCIDENT - POSS PERSON TRAPPED|GAS BOTTLE EXPLOSION) )|CNR).*?(?= [A-Z]+ [0-9]+)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^    ^^^
                                          1                                        2
```

Where you can see the first part are the part not to be matched and the second part those to  match.

Note that regex is not very practical if you have different variations of phrases before the address. If you can identify some pattern though, that would be regex a more suitable tool :)

---

EDIT: Following update, you might try something like this:

```
((?<=(?:GAS PIPE LEAK|FIRE|RHS|ROOF|TRAPPED|EXPLOSION|ALARMS) )|CNR).*?(?= SV[NCSEW]| M\b)
```

I tested it on [regexhero.net](http://regexhero.net/tester/) but since I can't create a permalink without paying for an account, here are the results with your 8 sample inputs:

```
MAIN HWY SUBURB
CNR SAMPLE ST/EXAMPLE ST SUBURB
MAIN HWY SUBURB
SAMPLE ST/EXAMPLE ST SUBURB
JACARANDA ST SUBURB /ROAD ST
JACARANDA ST SUBURB /ROAD ST
123 JACARANDA ST SUBURB /ROAD ST
JACARANDA ST SUBURB /ROAD ST
```

Otherwise, your current regex is not that readable with all those nested capture groups. You might consider turning some into non-capture groups and regroup some of the options with the beginning numbers:

```
(?:CNR|\b\d+(?:\s?[/-]\s?\d+)?\b).*?(?= SV[NCSEW]| M\b)|(?<=(?:GAS PIPE LEAK|FIRE ALARM|SMOKE ALARMS|FIRE|TRAPPED|EXPLOSION) ).*?(?= SV[NCSEW]| M\b)
```

I added some more options in the lookahead and removed the lone pipe `|` at the end of your lookahead.

[I also use `\b` instead of spaces generally. `\b` matches a word boundary, meaning it'll match only at the beginning or end of a 'word' (word is alphanumeric and includes underscore)]

Comment: Thanks Jerry, I agree that regex is not 100% practical for what i am trying to achieve, however it does fit the best out of all the options. I am finding some patterns in the messages (e.g. some have CNR, some have street numbers, and others have various phrases i can extract for, it just makes for a monster regex).

Comment: @user1829564 I edited my answer and included a new regex (and also added an edited version of your current regex). See if this works better :)